# How to convert from text to number integer?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

i have input only number from text field and i want to change it to integer. what code should i write in?

just say text field say for 10 and i want to take that 10 = x, x = integer. so if i use it for mathematic process a = x + 1 and display say 11. is there any chance? i hope you understand what i mean. thank you. i think both of you will answer this simple question but i not because im beginner. im a 3d design graphic switch 180 degree become xcode programming. BTW ive tried this before but it cant.

```
 NSInteger number = [[txtBtn text] integerValue];
```

**Edited :**

i've got this error, local declaration of 'number' hides instance variable, pointed to number at result = (number * 2) - 1; and i put the code like this.

```
NSInteger number = [[txtBtn text] intValue];
result = (number * 2) - 1;
```

i dont know whats wrong.

Comment: That code sample should work. Are you using Interface Builder?

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. thank you. no problem now. haha, i really stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's a TextField and not a UIButton you are trying to get the integerValue from?

`[txtBtn text]`

I created a TextField and a UIButton, and implemented your code:

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender {
    NSInteger i = [[inputField text] intValue];
    int result = (i*2)-1;
    NSLog(@"%i", result);
}
```

the output results is correct.
ex: type 5, output in console is 9.

Comment: no, because my IBAction using UITextField as first responder. so thats why i want to take my input by UITextField to convert to be integer for next step. but anyway, your code is right, same as mine. thank you for your help.